# scanning the barcode and control led

Tags: barcode-scanner

I have a serial barcode scanner  and Arduino Uno.
I need to configuration..one Correct barcode scanning led on.

my code is

```
void setup ()
{
Serial.begin (9600);
 pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
}


void loop ()
{


if(Serial.available())
{
String command =Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
Serial.println(command);
if(command =="1010007")
{
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(4,LOW);}
else
if(command !="1010007")
{digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);}


}}
```

im scanning barcode  1010007   it showing serial monitor   g⸮⸮⸮⸮ like this
how to fix it

plz help

and i try another code it showing correctly barcode,,,,,i scan 1010007  serial monitor also same 1010007

but led not on...code is below,,,

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial barcode = SoftwareSerial(2, 3, true); // RX, TX 
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(3, OUTPUT);

 
 barcode.begin(9600);

 delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
 if(barcode.available())
 {
   
  char data = barcode.read();
   Serial.write(data);
   
   if(data=="101007")
 {
 digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
 }
}}
```